# Mathmatic AST in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am currently trying to write an AST in Haskell. More specifically, I have a parser that converts text to AST and then I want to be able to simplify an AST into another AST.

For example `x + x + x`

-> `Add (Add (Variable 'x') (Variable 'x')) (Variable 'x')`

-> `(Mul (Literal 3) (Variable 'x'))`

-> `3x`

I have found other examples but none that take into account different data types. I want to use this approach to allow simplification rules depending on what the inner type of the left and right side of a binary expression is.

Here is roughly what I have so far for my datatypes:

```
data UnaryExpression o = Literal o
                       | Variable Char

data BinaryExpression l lo r ro = Add (l lo) (r ro)
                                | Mul (l lo) (r ro)
                                | Exp (l lo) (r ro)
                                -- etc...
```

I think I have 2 problems:
First, I need to have the correct data structure, and being new to Haskell, I am not sure what is the correct approach.
Second, I need to have my simplify function that is aware of the left and right datatypes. I feel like there should be a way to do this, but I am not sure.

Comment: Why don't you have just a single expression type? `data Expr = Literal Integer | Variable Char | Add Expr Expr | Mul Expr Expr | ...`

Comment: How can your parser possibly produce a value of this type? Do you plan to have a different parse function for every supported structure of expression (meaning you don't support arbitrary nesting)? Or do you want it to be polymorphic and then you supply the structure as a type argument? But then that would still require you to know the structure of the expression before parsing the string.

Comment: @melpomene, because you cannot have a Literal with different inner types, as stated in my original post. If I were to use that structure, I would be using the exact structure laid out in numerous AST tutorials online that I said I read and chose not to use

Comment: @sepp2k. The aim is to have each binary expression to have a left and right type. If there was an Add nested in an Add, for example, I would need something in place to say "an `Add Integer Double` is reduce-able to a `Double`. So at any point in time, there are only two types on each side. Something like `Add (Add Int Variable) Double` only has to keep track of two inner types at each level

Comment: @ChaseWalden I'm asking what you want the type of `parse someString` should be. The way I've understood you so far, you'd want the expression `2 * (3 + 4.0)` to be represented as a `BinaryExpression UnaryExpression Integer (BinaryExpression UnaryExpression Integer UnaryExpression) Double` and `42` as `UnaryExpression Integer`. But you've also said that you have a parser, so you're not just writing down ASTs manually in code - you're converting arbitrary strings to ASTs. So you have a `parse` function of type `String -> ?` and I'm asking what goes in the place of `?`.

Comment: Sure you can have different literal types: `... LitInt Integer | LitDouble Double | ...`.

Comment: @sepp2k my parser is being ported currently. I previously had all literal as Double, but since I keep changing the structure of my AST, I need to keep changing my parser every time I change the datatypes. Therefore, currently, I am writing the AST manually for testing in the GHCI

Comment: @melpomene, yes but that also means that I need a different literal for every type I support rather than being able to extend the parser using typeclasses. Maybe this is not possible since I am recently moving from OOP to functional-like languages

Answer (score 3):

So I think what you actually want is something like this:

- `AST o` should be a mathematical expression representing a value of numerical type `o`.
- This can be either a literal of type `o`, or a binary expression containing expressions that represent *more specialised* number types than `o` (e.g. `Int` being more specialised than `Double`).

First, always keep it simple and *avoid duplication*, so we should only have one constructor in `AST` for all binary operators. For distinguishing between different operators, make a separate variant type:

```
data NumOperator = Addition | Multiplication | Exponentiation
```

Then, you need to have some way what you mean by “more specialised number type”. Haskell has a bunch of numerical classes, but no standard notion of which types are more general than which others. One library for that implements this is [convertible](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/convertible-1.1.1.0/docs/Data-Convertible-Base.html#v:convert), but it's a bit too liberal “convert anything into anything else regardless of whether it's semantically clear how”. Here a simple version:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class ConvertNum a b where
  convertNum :: a -> b

instance ConvertNum Int Int where convertNum = id
instance ConvertNum Double Double where convertNum = id
...
instance ConvertNum Int Double where convertNum = fromIntegral
...
```

Then, you need a way to store different types in the binary-operator constructor. This is *existential quantification*, best expressed with a GADT:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data AST o where
  Literal :: o -> AST o
  Variable :: String -> AST o
  BinaryExpression :: (ConvertNum ol o, ConvertNum or o)
          => NumOperator -> AST ol -> AST or -> AST o
```

Comment: This is interesting, I will give this a try and see how it ends up

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for this, I ran into the same problem and was prepared to write some weird stuff to make it work :)